# Get result and ids variable in 1 SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex select statement which I want to return to the application layer. At the same time I want to reuse ids from this statement. I've come to the table variable solution like this

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (SortOrder int IDENTITY, Id bigint, data_columns, PRIMARY KEY (Id))
INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT Id, data_columns ...

--output to the app layer
SELECT Id, data_columns FROM @Result ORDER BY SortOrder;

--using @Result Id elsewhere
```

SortOrder is used to keep original order from the first select. Without it I faced a strange bug in ms sql server 2012. 
PRIMARY KEY (Id) is used as a hint to optimizer that Id values are unique. SortOrder does not correlate with Id.

Now I have concerns about memory and cpu overload. Does anyone have a better solution?

----- Addition:
This can be an answer

```
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (Id bigint, PRIMARY KEY (Id));

MERGE @Ids AS ids
USING (SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807 Id, data_columns ...) AS result
ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES(result.Id)
OUTPUT result.*; --output to the app layer here

--using @Ids Id elsewhere
```

I can confirm it works on my sample and takes less time.
But I'm still worried about order in the OUTPUT.

TOP hack explained [MERGE INTO insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884187/merge-into-insertion-order)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) also says

> There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied
>   to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the
>   output table or table variable will correspond.

Luckily I don't care about order in @Ids table. But it's important to get the same order in OUTPUT clause as it was in USING ()

Comment: What concerns?  What has led to these concerns?

Comment: 1. Size of table variable. I don't need to store data_columns after output

Comment: There is not enough information for anyone to help you.  What do you mean by "Size of Table"?

Comment: Also what strange bug did you face? I'm pretty sure if it's just the order you get the data in it's not a bug at all.

Comment: It could be 100 data columns which I have to copy into table variable together with Id column

Comment: Bug explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064532/the-order-of-a-sql-select-statement-without-order-by-clause

Comment: That is not a bug, as the answer explains. Why do you need a table variable? Why can't you just do `SELECT Id, data_columns .. ORDER BY Id;` using the first SELECT?

Comment: I agree, it was bug for me, for RDBMS it's by design.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to persist a particular sort order in which case you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to produce the desired effect:

```
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OriginalSortingColumns) AS SortOrder                  
       , data_columns 
    FROM sourcetable
```

But without knowing more about the purpose of your program and about the structure and nature of your data I can't be sure.  It's well worth reading this guide - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - to make sure you provide all the info we need to get you a great answer quickly.

As the comments say you can never rely on keys to order the data, that is what the `ORDER BY`statement is for.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm asking a technical question. I believe that providing details in SELECT statement instead of three dots will give me partial answers. I made another addition to my question